# What's the MSIL to call a base class's event handler?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

I have a class called EventConsumer which defines an event EventConsumed and a method OnEventConsumed as follows:

```
public event EventHandler EventConsumed;

public virtual void OnEventConsumed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EventConsumed != null)
        EventConsumed(this, e);
}
```

I need to add attributes to the at OnEventConsumed runtime, so I'm generating a subclass using System.Reflection.Emit.  What I want is the MSIL equivalent of this:

```
public override void OnEventConsumed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEventConsumed(sender, e);
}
```

What I have so far is this:

```
...

MethodInfo baseMethod = typeof(EventConsumer).GetMethod("OnEventConsumed");
MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("OnEventConsumed",
                                                       baseMethod.Attributes,
                                                       baseMethod.CallingConvention,
                                                       typeof(void),
                                                       new Type[] {typeof(object),
                                                                   typeof(EventArgs)});

ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

// load the first two args onto the stack
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

// call the base method
ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, baseMethod, new Type[0] );

// return
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

...
```

I create the type, create an instance of the type, and call its OnEventConsumed function, and I get:

```
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

...which is not exactly helpful.  What am I doing wrong?  What's the correct MSIL to call the base class's event handler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the IL from a sample app:

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance void OnEventConsumed(object sender, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs e) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: nop 
        L_0001: ldarg.0 
        L_0002: ldarg.1 
        L_0003: ldarg.2 
        L_0004: call instance void SubclassSpike.BaseClass::OnEventConsumed(object, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs)
        L_0009: nop 
        L_000a: ret 
    }
```

So I think you aren't loading the instance because you aren't doing a ldarg.0

Answer (score 1):

I was actually really close - the problem was that I wasn't loading the 'this' argument, and that Callvirt calls the subclass method, where I actually wanted Call.  So that section becomes:

```
// load 'this' and the first two args onto the stack
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

// call the base method
ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, baseMethod, new Type[0] );

// return
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The using

```
public virtual void OnEventConsumed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EventConsumed != null)
        EventConsumed(this, e);
}
```

should be

```
public virtual void OnEventConsumed(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = this.EventConsumed;
    if ( null != handler ) handler( this, e );
}
```

.

I think, you should use a [ILGenerator.EmitCalli](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d81ee808.aspx) and you should pass a type of return value ( i think null in this case ) and pass the types of arguments - i think "new Type[]{ typeof(EventArgs)}

Comment: It's cause the multithreading. If you check "EventConsumed != null", an another thread can be activated, remove the delegate from event, then the first thread will be activated, the "EventConsumed" will be null, and the "EventConsumed(this, e)" will fail on NullReferenceException.